# Unable to run Micronaut apps

Tags: gradle, groovy, micronaut

I am exploring security oauth2.0 in micronaut framework with groovy.I generated project from micronaut site.

https://micronaut.io/launch/

Micronaut Version : 2.5.9
Language : Groovy
Build : Gradle
Test Framework : JUnit

When i got below error after running apps

```
[main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.OauthClientConfigurationProperties] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.OauthClientConfigurationProperties]: Could not resolve placeholder ${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.OauthClientConfigurationProperties] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.OauthClientConfigurationProperties]: Could not resolve placeholder ${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1568)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:234)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2905)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:231)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:180)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:71)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:311)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:297)
        at com.example.Application.main(Application.groovy:9)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.OauthClientConfigurationProperties]: Could not resolve placeholder ${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2008)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2768)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2754)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2292)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1562)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not resolve placeholder ${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
        at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver$PlaceholderSegment.getValue(DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.java:260)
        at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.java:86)
        at io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourcePropertyResolver.resolvePlaceHoldersIfNecessary(PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java:799)
        at io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourcePropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java:303)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.getProperty(DefaultApplicationContext.java:200)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveValue(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1946)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getValueForMethodArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:793)
        at io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.$OauthClientConfigurationPropertiesDefinition.injectBean(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.$OauthClientConfigurationPropertiesDefinition.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.build(AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.java:118)
        at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:149)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1979)
        ... 12 common frames omitted

> Task :run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `OAUTH_CLIENT_ID` - that is what the error messages states.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the oauth configuration as specified in the docs:
https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-oauth2-github-gradle-java.html#oauth-2-0-configuration
i.e. `client-id:  '${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID:defaultToken}'`
Replace `defaultToken` with whatever your token is